# How to go back at previous scene

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making 3 scenes in javafx scenebuilder.

```
Scene A: Edit Record -> Scene C

Scene B: View Record -> Scene C

Scene C: View Data
```

How can I go back to the previous scene(A or B) without creating a duplicate Scene C.

```
public void view(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    Parent mainpanelForm = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene A or Scene B file location"));
    Scene mainpanelUI = new Scene(mainpanelForm);                 
    Stage mainpanel = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();  
    mainpanel.setScene(mainpanelUI);
    mainpanel.centerOnScreen();     
    mainpanel.setMaximized(true);
    mainpanel.show(); 
}
```

Comment: You'd need to store a reference to the previous scene, then use that scene rather than creating a new one.

Comment: I have answered another, but similar, question if you want to have a look at some code, though it's just as Slaw said. You just need to store a reference instead of creating a new scene when you want to switch back and forth between your scenes. Here is the question I mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360993/how-to-stop-javafx-slider-controls-from-resetting-to-their-default-values-when-s/55362179#55362179